# Estimating the convexity of black box objective function , by multi starting a gradient based method.

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

In the context of optimisation of a differentiable black box function, I have a simulation, which gives me some scalar result depending on the choice of some continuous design variables with upper and lower bounds.

My idea was to run  a gradient based optimisation algorithm (like conjugate gradient), from many different starting points. And if the algorithm always returns to the same (or very similar) value of the design variables, to conclude that there is a global optimum, no local optima, thus that the function is likely convex. And conversely if it returns different optima that the function must be non convex.

My primary question is if this line of reasoning is valid?
and secondly if there are maybe better ways to estimate convexity for black box functions?

Comment: You can disprove convexity this way, but you can't prove it without exhaustive search.

Answer (score 1):

This line of reasoning is not valid, for two simple reasons:

1. Nonconvex functions can also have one global minimizer. For example $f(x)=-e^{-x^2}$
2. You have no way of knowing which point will the gradient method converge to.

I do not recommend such 'experimental' methods, since they do not reveal **why** the function is convex. However, if you do insist on checking convexity on some *compact* domain $D$  by performing a simulation, I would do it using the gradient inequality. Namely, choose random points $x, y \in D$ and verify that
$$
f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (y - x)
$$
and
$$
f(x) \geq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^T (x - y)
$$
If for some pair of points one of the inequalities does not hold, the function is not convex.

Comment: Interesting example. Is there a particular name for the class of functions for which all gradient based methods will converge to the global optimum? I thought this was the class of convex functions, but your example shows that gradient based methods will also work on some other functions. Is the name maybe "Unimodal" functions? Thanks also for the gradient inequality, to check convexity.

Comment: I believe that under some conditions, the gradient method converges to a stationary point. That is, a point for which $\nabla f = 0$. Functions for which $\nabla f(x) = 0$ implies that $x$ is a global minimum are called, to the best of my knowledge, pseudoconvex functions.

Comment: So that implies that if i replace convex, with pseudo convex the assumption in the question is valid,, right? It seems that pseudoconvex functions can have more stationary points. So if the test is succesfull when the number of repetitions goes to infinity that would seem to imply, that the function is  pseudoconvex, with a single stationary point. Is there anything about such functions that would make it harder to optimize such a function than a normal convex function? If no that would mean that although i used the wrong terminology, in practice, the test works right?

Comment: Convexity not only guarantees convergence to a global optimum under mild assumptions, but also affects the *speed* of convergence. For convex functions, a gradient method can be made much faster than for non-convex functions.